# SQL Server where field is null or not null or both?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, checkbox, parameter-passing

I have pretty annoying problem with sql statment. I am using stored procedure (have to) and I can not use dynamic sql.

Let say I have this table:

**PEOPOLE**

```
ID NAME     SURNAME  MARRIED  COMPANY  PAYMENTID
---------------------------------------------------   
1  Michael  Backer      1     Google    1
2  Travis   Morgan      null  null    null 
3  George   Marshall    null  null    null
4  Trevor   Rush        1     Microsoft  1
5  John     Doe         1     IBM        2
```

I have two checkboxes on my ASP.NET (C#) site. First is 'Married' and the second is 'Not married'.

If user check only first checbox result are rows with id 1 and 4, if the second checbox is checked then result are rows with id 2 and 3. If both checboxes are checked then result are the whole table (id from 1-4). Keep in mind that I have one serach box which check for some person name, surname, so that is also in sql statment.

How can I manage to do what I want with stored procedure, because I cant pass value like 'IS NOT NULL' or 'IS NULL'. Any suggestion?

**Examples of searching:**

User can choose which company and payment is included (always **at least** one of each) in searching and check checboxes for marital status. I passed company and payment parameters to stored procedure and used it in IN statement.

1. Example (the most complicated):
   User include Google and Microosft and all paymentid-s to searching. If both marriage checboxes are checekd (first and second) then results are people with ID 1, 3, and because of second checxbox are checked also 2 and 3 (where company is null value).
2. Example: User Include all companies and all paymentid-s, and check only second checbox, which says 'not married'. So results are people with ID 2 and 3. In this case you can see that companies and paymentid-s are not important beacuse of null value *(possible join statement?)*.
3. Example: User Include all companies and paymentsid-s (or not) and checed only those who are married (first checkbox), so results are people who are married and those who works in selected company.

User can in every scenario search after name, surname, etc..

My sql:

```
WHERE
  (
    (@MarriageCheck IS NULL) or
    (@MarriageCheck = 0 AND Marriage IS NULL) or
    (@MarriageCheck = 1 AND Marriage IS NOT NULL)
  ) and
  (
   people.company in ('Google') AND  // google is parameter @companies 
   people.payment in ('1','2') AND // payment is parameter @payment (splited by , using xml)
   people.name LIKE %Mic% AND
   people.surname LIKE %bac%
...
  )
```

*Just for information, because is not really important: I resolved passing IN paramter using xml split (it works).*

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if neither box is checked? You seem to have 4 UI states mapping to only 3 search types.

Comment: Thanks for warning. It should be like first checkbox is checked.

Comment: Anyone? Spent whole night to solved this problem without success.

Answer (score 1):

use `DBNull.Value` from the front end.

example: Suppose I have a class and the object is `AgeItem` having a property `AgeIndex` I can check for null values as follow.

```
Parameter.Value = (object)AgeItem.AgeIndex ?? DBNull.Value;
```

In you database check for null values in the parameter.

### Edit 1

```
//check what you have to send value of null
//if null then pass BDNull.Value
//else the value
cmd.Parameters.Add("@marriedcheck", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value=?;
```

Comment: Thank you, but an you please explain with more details what to do in stored procedure?
I pass parameter like that:
cmd.Parameters.Add("@marriedcheck", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value=?;
Also I do not know which type I should choose, I thnik NvarChar is inappropriate.

Comment: varchar will also work. You need to check values while assigning to the parameter If not checked the pass dbtyp.null.

Comment: I resolved this using comment of @Damien_The_Unbeliever. But need help in sql (look up). If you have any suggestion please help. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I would write the `WHERE` clause as:

```
WHERE (@MarriageCheck IS NULL) or
      (@MarriageCheck = 0 AND Marriage IS NULL) or
      (@MarriageCheck = 1 AND Marriage IS NOT NULL)
```

Where `@MarriageCheck` is a new parameter of type `bit`. It should be an easy bit of conditional logic to set that value correctly in your C# code:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@MarriageCheck",SqlDbType.Bit)
if(!(chkFirst.Checked&&chkSecond.Checked))
{
   cmd.Parameters["@MarriageCheck"].Value = !chkSecond.Checked;
}
else
{
   cmd.Parameters["@MarriageCheck"].Value = DBNull.Value;
}
```

(Updated so "neither" is treated the same as if the first checkbox is checked)

---

Usually, if you want to do some other form of checks also (e.g. `company`), I'd arrange the `WHERE` clause as:

```
WHERE
  (
    (@MarriageCheck IS NULL) or
    (@MarriageCheck = 0 AND Marriage IS NULL) or
    (@MarriageCheck = 1 AND Marriage IS NOT NULL)
  ) and
  (
    --Company conditions go in here
  )
```

Comment: It works great if only one is checked. If both are checked does not work. I do not know what should be in else statment (chckSecond.Checked?). If both are unchecked  It should be like first checkbox is checked.

Comment: @michael24B - if both are checked, it should never enter the `if` block, which should leave the parameter's value left as `NULL`/`DbNull` - which is what we wanted it set to to include both result types.

Comment: If both are checked I get this exception:
Procedure or function 'Procedure' expects parameter '@MarriageCheck', which was not supplied.

Comment: I've added an explicit set, but I didn't think it was necessary. You should make sure that, in SQL, your parameter to your stored procedure is declared as `@MarriageCheck bit = null`

Comment: Thanks for that tip it works know for both checkboxes. But there is another problem.. User also search for company, so I have this procedure: 
WHERE (@MarriageCheck IS NULL AND people.company in ('Google') AND people.anothercolumn('value')) or
(@MarriageCheck = 0 AND Marriage IS NULL) or
(@MarriageCheck = 1 AND Marriage IS NOT NULL AND people.company in ('Google'))

It works great for first checbox, but if both are checked (so first line of code is not good, because it shows only people who are married.

Comment: Well, the only people that you know of that work at Google are married. Do you want the company search to be `company = 'Google' or company is null`?

Comment: I want to show both, if both checkboxes are checked. Is that even possible?

Comment: It's getting really difficult to tell exactly what it is that you're after. Could you edit your question and add some example searches, and what the expected results are for each of those? You might need to expand your sample data also.

Comment: Done. Check first post.